# How to print integers and memory addresses to the console using write()?

Tags: c

I am in a situation where I cannot use `printf()` to print to the console in C.
It's a university assignment and we're reimplementing malloc, calloc, free and realloc. I am using ubuntu and when I call `printf()`, it seg faults as `printf()` uses malloc in its implementation (according to my lecturer), so I can't use it and have to use `write()` instead.

So if I have a simple program, how can I print an integer and a pointer address to the console using `write()`.

I have tried:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
   int a = 12345;
   int* ptr = &a;
   
   // none of the following seem to work
   write(2, &a, sizeof(a));
   write(2, "\n", 1);
   write(2, ptr, sizeof(ptr));
   write(2, "\n", 1);
   write(2, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
   write(2, "\n", 1);

   return 0;
}
```

The output was

```
90
90
xZ???
```

Thanks, Juan

Comment: You need to convert all values to *text*.

Comment: In what _format_ do you want to represent the number? You have written it successfully in your machine native format.

Comment: I think the number 2 is for standard error and 1 is for standard output although it's not the answer, just saying, since you want to write  to stdout

Comment: @KamilCuk, I just want the number to print in the console. Just as if I wrote printf("%d", a);

Comment: @SayominSam , yeah thats true, either way it prints to the console

Comment: Then you may want to follow @Someprogrammerdude it works when you convert the value to text

Comment: By the way, `write(2, ptr, sizeof(ptr))` should really be `write(2, ptr, sizeof(*ptr))`

Comment: @SaymoinSam haha seems like it!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why `sizeof(*ptr)` instead of `sizeof(ptr)` don't they have the same size?! since they're both pointers, if not can you explain

Comment: Because when you do `write(2, ptr, sizeof(...))` you write the data where `ptr` is pointing. It's exactly the same as `write(2, &a, sizeof(...))`. And `sizeof(ptr)` is the size of the *pointer*, not the value where it points, which is `sizeof(*ptr)`. If `sizeof(ptr) != sizeof(*ptr)` (which is typically true on 64-bit systems) then using `sizeof(ptr)` will lead `write` to go outside the memory or `a` and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, sorry it was like I saw `write(2, ptr, sizeof(&ptr))` I didn't see it as `write(2, ptr, sizeof(*ptr))` I was confused because right now I'm learning android development :) and that's why I said they're both pointers. but thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int` value `12345` is equal to `0x0000003039` (assuming 4-byte `int`).

On a little-endian system (like a standard x86 or x86-64 PC) it's stored in the sequence `0x39 0x30 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`.

In ASCII encoding `0x39` is the character `'9'` and `0x30` is `'0'`.

So printing the value `12345` will print the two characters `90`, and then some unprintable zeros.

You need to convert the values to *text* to be able to print them. Perhaps like this:

```
char value[128];

snprintf(value, sizeof value, "%d", a);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, value, strlen(value));
```

---

If you're not allowed to use even `snprintf` (or `sprintf`) then you need to come up with some other way to convert the number to text.

Comment: Great, yep this does the job with ```snprintf()```. I also did the same thing with the pointer but changed the ```%d``` to ```%p```. I'm sure that's obvious to you but just incase anyone if looking at this later and doesn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Decide on the *format* you want to output the number. As a hex number? Decimal number? In octal? In base64?
2. Write a conversion function between `uintptr_t` to a string. `uintptr_t` is the type that may be used to convert a pointer to a number.
3. Convert numbers to string.
4. Write the string.

The following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char *uintptr_to_string(char *dest, size_t n, void *v0) {
    uintptr_t v = (uintptr_t)v0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(v) * 2; ++i) {
        if (n-- == 0) return NULL;
        const short idx = (v >> (sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT - 4));
        const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
        *dest++ = hex[idx];
        v <<= 4;
    }
    return dest;
}
int main() {
   char string[200];
   int a;
   char *end = uintptr_to_string(string, sizeof(string), &a);
   printf("%018p\n", (void*)&a);
   write(STDOUT_FILENO, "0x", 2);
   write(STDOUT_FILENO, string, end - string);
   write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
}
```

[may output on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jEn46x):

```
0x00007ffffd3d0a9c
0x00007ffffd3d0a9c
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, I did however use the ```snprintf``` answer by @Some programmer dude and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

> I am in a situation where I cannot use printf() to print to the console in C. It's a university assignment and we're reimplementing malloc, calloc, free and realloc. I am using ubuntu

### You are lucky. Ubuntu is mostly [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software,

So the code of `printf`, `malloc` etc... is inside [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (or [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/)) whose source code (above [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) provided by the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/)) you can read and study.

Read of course [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) (and later the C standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf)).

Use [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) and [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the behavior of your (or others) program.

If you compile with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get warnings and [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information for the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Once your code is correct, [add](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-O2` to get compiler optimizations. If you want some [formal proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) of your code, consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/).

**Mention in your assignment the source code that you did actually read.** Your teacher would appreciate.

Of course, you need to convert your `int a;` into a string buffer such as `char buf[80];`; **avoid [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and other kinds of [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)**. You might not be allowed to use [snprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html), but you surely can mimic its code and behavior. Converting an `int` to some [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) string is an easy exercise (assuming you understand what a [decimal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) is).

The intuition is that for a small `int x` between 0 and 9 included, its decimal digit in ASCII is `(char)('0'+x)` or `"0123456789"[x]`. To convert a bigger number, use the `%` [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and `/` integral division operators cleverly in a simple loop.

For [IBM Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Z) main frames using [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), it should be similar.

### The full code is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score -2):

You need to multiply sizeof() by the size of a byte

Comment: `sizeof char` is always `1`.

Comment: @SergejChristoforov he said *"the size of a byte"*!!! a byte is a byte!!! what does he mean?!!!

Comment: That the size of a byte is 1. Multiplying something by the size of a byte, is multiplying by 1.